# What is the meaning of "Now" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "Now" in the following sentence,

> "No one else can weave as well as I can," Arachne boasted. "Not even
>   the goddess Minerva could make anything so lovely and fine." Now
>   Minerva wove the cloth for all the gods. She was proud of her weaving,
>   too, and thought that no human could ever match her work.

?

Does "Now" mean "As a result that Arachne boasted" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, **now** is simply used to transition to an important point (definition 3 [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/now)). A comma could follow "now" without changing the meaning. Without "now," you might interpret the sentence to mean that Minerva did her weaving *after* Arachne's boast.

Although you're correct that "now" sometimes indicates a consequence (broadly, definitions 5 and 6 in the link), that's not the case here; you should not interpret "now" to mean that Arachne's boast prompted Minerva to start weaving.

Other ways to express the same meaning are

> **At the time**, Minerva wove the cloth for all the gods.
>
> **You must realize that** Minerva wove the cloth for all the gods.
>
> **Notably**, Minerva wove the cloth for all the gods.
>
> **It was Minerva who** wove the cloth for all the gods.
>
> **Consider this**: Minerva wove the cloth for all the gods.
>
> **But guess what?** Minerva wove the cloth for all the gods.
>
> **For your information**, Minerva wove the cloth for all the gods.
>
> **Surprise!** Minerva wove the cloth for all the gods.